# Meteor - Account.createUser in client and server

Tags: validation, meteor

I understand the reason to have the business logic in both client and server, but I don't understand well how to do that in some situations. Here for example:

```js
// client/client.js
// hnadling click event on the Create Accounts button
Template.homecontent.events({
  'click #btnCreateAccount': function (event, template) {
    var userEmail = template.find('#email').value,
      userName  = template.find('#newusername').value,
      password  = template.find('#newpassword').value,
      password2 = template.find('#password2').value,
      name      = template.find('#fullname').value;

    validates = true;
   //do some validation here
   if(password != password2) {
      validates = false;
   }

    if(validates === true) {
      Accounts.createUser({
        username: userName,
        email:    userEmail,
        password: password,
        profile: {
          name: name
        }
      }, function (error) {
        if (error) {
          console.log("Cannot create user");
        }
      });
    }
  }
});
```

Since the validation is on the client only, it can easily be bypassed.
But there's a problem here: this is triggered by a user event, so I'm not sure what's the best way to have this code running on client & server.

Comment: Check out this question, alredy answered it with a server/client code to create usere with Roles, actally im using that code on my web to create users hope it helps [Code working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27585020/meteorjs-useraccountscore-and-meteor-roles/27597448#27597448)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You may be looking for something like `Meteor.methods();`, which allows you to define functions on the server that the client can call using `Meteor.call()`. You could provide a validation function and a user save function on the server, and call them both from the client, passing in the form data.

What I have done in the past is (on the client) I have a `userFormParse()` function that takes a form object and parses it into an object that can be passed into a server side validation function. I use the same userFormParse function for user edit and creation forms.

The validation function returns an error object to the client, or, if it's all valid data, I'll pass the data object on to a `userCreateWithRole` function (I usually always have roles assigned to users).

On the server:

```js
Meteor.methods({
  'createUserWithRole': function(data, role) {
    var userId;

    Meteor.call('createUserNoRole', data, function(err, result) {
      if (err) {
        return err;
      }
      Roles.addUsersToRoles(result, role);
      return userId = result;
    });
    return userId;
  },
  'createUserNoRole': function(data) {
    //Do server side validation
    return Accounts.createUser({
      email: data.email,
      password: data.password,
      profile: data.profile
    });
  }
});
```

And then on the client:

```js
Template.userSignup.events({
  'submit #userSignup': function(event) {
    var data, validationErrors;
    event.preventDefault();
    data = userInputParse($(event.target)); //this function parses form into user object that can be inserted
    validationErrors = userObjectValidate(data); //this function takes and does client side validation on the user object.
    data.profile.status = 0;
    if (validationErrors) {
      //Show the user the validation errors
    } else {
      return Meteor.call('createUserWithRole', data, 'standard', function(err, userId) {
        if (!err) {
          //User created!!
        } else {
          //Insertion Error
        }
      });
    }
  }
});
```

That code is conceptual and untested :)

Comment: Patrick, any chance you can share the code for that function? I'm just trying to make one work myself. Ta.

Comment: This will send the plain password over the wire, you should do it like @Andrey suggested and use Accounts.onCreateUser() to add validation on the server-side.

Answer (score 5):

You should be doing it on server side, using [Accounts.onCreateUser](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/accounts_oncreateuser)

Answer (score 5):

The previous answers are not really exact.

Creating and using a Meteor method won't stop users to call the `Accounts.createUser` from the console for example. Therefore you also need to prevent the creation of users on the client :

```
Accounts.config({
  forbidClientAccountCreation : true
});
```

You might want to look into [`Accounts.validateNewUser`](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/accounts_validatenewuser).

Example (taken from the docs):

```js
Accounts.validateNewUser(function (user) {
  if (user.username && user.username.length >= 3)
    return true;
  throw new Meteor.Error(403, "Username must have at least 3 characters");
});
```