# MeteorJS useraccounts:core and meteor-roles

Tags: javascript, authentication, meteor

I am using MeteorJS to develop simple web app. I am new at MeteorJs. I use  useraccounts:core package and meteor-roles by alanning. Is it posible to assign role to user while registering a new user ?

**EDIT 1**

I have tried using onCreateUser hook but something is not working.

```
Accounts.onCreateUser(function(options, user){
  var role = ['unselected'];
  Roles.addUsersToRoles(user, role);
  return user;
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have this way to create users (if i understond you example you alredy have some users, just need some roles, so with the current user just create this), also use some Login buttons customized or something like that

**Server.js**

```
Meteor.methods({
     createUsers: function(email,password,roles,name){
       var users = [{name:name,email:email,roles:[roles]},
                   ];
.each(users, function (user) {
   var id;
id = Accounts.createUser({
     email: user.email,
     password: password,
     profile: { name: user.name }
     });
 if (user.roles.length > 0) {
          Roles.addUsersToRoles(id, user.roles);
         }
        });
},
       deleteUser : function(id){       ///Some Delete Method (ignore if dont needed)
      return Meteor.users.remove(id);
      },
    });
```

**Publish Methods**

```
//publish roles
      Meteor.publish(null, function (){ 
       return Meteor.roles.find({})
       })
Meteor.publish("Super-Admin", function () {
        var user = Meteor.users.findOne({_id:this.userId});

         if (Roles.userIsInRole(user, ["Super-Admin"])) {
        return Meteor.users.find({}, {fields: {emails: 1, profile: 1, roles: 1}});
         } 
   this.stop();
          return;
       });

          Meteor.publish("Admin", function () {
       var user = Meteor.users.findOne({_id:this.userId});

        if (Roles.userIsInRole(user, ["Admin"])) {
        return Meteor.users.find({}, {fields: {emails: 1, profile: 1, roles: 1}});
       } 
this.stop();
     return;
      });
      Meteor.publish(null, function (){ 
     return Meteor.roles.find({})
     })
```

**So on the Client side client/register.html**

```
<template name="register">
      <form id="register-form" action="action" >
        <input type="email" id="register-email" placeholder="Nombre Nuevo Usuario">
        <input type="password" id="register-password" placeholder="Password">        
          <select id="register-rol" class="form-control">
             <option value="Admin" selected>Admin</option>
            <option value="Super-Admin" selected>Super Admin</option>
            <option value="Normal" selected>Normal</option>
         </select>
       <input type="submit" value="Register">
      </form>
    </tempalate>
```

and on **register.js** call the server methods

```
 Template.registrar.events({
  'submit #register-form' : function(e, t) {
    e.preventDefault();    
     var email = t.find('#register-email').value,
     password = t.find('#register-password').value,
      roles = $( "#register-rol" ).val();
    Meteor.call("createUsers", email, password,roles);
     return false;
      },
    'click #deleteUser' : function(event,template){
     var idUsuario= this._id;
     Meteor.call('deleteUser',{_id:idUsuario})
     }
    });
```

**Delete Part(html)** this is optional just too look if accounts are creating correctly

```
{{#each users}}
      <li id="user"><h6>{{email}}</h6><h6>{{roles}}</h6></li>
        <button id="deleteUser" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs" > Borrar Usuario        {{email}}       </button>
     {{/each}}
```

**client/registerList.js**

```
   Template.registrar.helpers({
         users: function () {
         return Meteor.users.find();
       },
        email: function () {
        return this.emails[0].address;
        },
       roles: function () {
       if (!this.roles) return '<none>';
    return this.roles.join(',');
      }
      });
```

**Remember Subscribe**

```
  Meteor.subscribe('Admin');
  Meteor.subscribe('Super-Admin');
```

Hope this help sorry for the messy code

Answer (score 2):

The below method must run on the server side only. The clue is that you need to create first the user, get the id from creation and then attach a role to it.

```
Meteor.methods({
rolesCreateUser: function (user) {

    if (_.isObject(user)) {

        if (user.username) {
            var id = Accounts.createUser({
                username: user.username,
                email: user.email,
                password: user.password
            });
            //We add roles to the user
            if (user.roles.length > 0) {                   
                Roles.addUsersToRoles(id, user.roles);
            }
            _.extend(user, {id: id});

            return user;
        }
    }
}   
});
```

And then on the client side call the method with user's data:

```
    Meteor.call('rolesCreateUser', newUserData, function (error, newCreatedUser) {

        if (error) {
            //The error code
        } else {
           //Do something with newCreatedUser
       }

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use OnCreateUser hook: http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/accounts_oncreateuser

Comment: Yes I have tried with that. I have posted code EDIT, but something is not working.

Comment: I think You need to do it after the user is created. I wonder if this will work:
var newUser = Accounts.onCreateUser(function(options, user){
  return user;
});
var role = ['unselected'];
Roles.addUsersToRoles(newUser, role);

Comment: TypeError: Accounts.onCreateUser is not a function

Comment: remember that this should be run on the server side

Comment: Again errors on server side.Error: Missing 'users' param.